# Can you create a noise using Minor Illusion/Thaumaturgy on an area you cannot see?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting

Can you create a noise using Minor Illusion/Thaumaturgy on an area you cannot see?

Just to make it more clear, let's say you are in a house and you know that there is a room on the other side of a wall. Can you create a sound on that other room? (You know that it exists and its dimensions)

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### You require a clear path to the point of origin for your spells.

Both [*Thaumaturgy*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/thaumaturgy) and [*Minor Illlusion*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/minor-illusion) target a point of origin for an area of effect (within your range).

You have to be able to target a specific point which requires a clear path, which you do not have because the wall provides total cover (unless there are holes in that wall or some other way that provides you with a clear path), but you can place the point of origin on your side of the wall:

**Targets** (PHB 204):

> A typical spell requires you to pick one or more targets to be
>   affected by the spell’s magic. A spell's description tells you whether
>   the spell targets creatures, objects, or a point of origin for an area
>   of effect (described below).

**A Clear Path to the Target** (PHB 204):

> To target something, you must have a clear path to it, so it can’t be
>   behind total cover. If you place an area of effect at a point that you
>   can’t see and an obstruction, such as a wall, is between you and that
>   point, the point of origin comes into being on the near side of that
>   obstruction.